# docker tomcat:9.0 [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy a war file downloaded from an S3 Bucket to a Tomcat created docker container deployed in kubernetes but I'm getting the following error:

`download failed: s3://folder/myapp.war to ../../usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myapp.war [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myapp.war.8bEd47FD'`

This is my Dockerfile, AWS configuration comes directly from k8s configuration

```
FROM tomcat:9.0

COPY --from=0 /usr/local/bin/creds-helper  /usr/local/bin/creds-helper

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools

RUN pip3 install awscli

RUN mkdir -p /scripts
COPY k8s/launch.sh /scripts/

RUN useradd -m -u 59417 -d /home/nonroot -s /bin/bash nonroot
USER 59417:59417

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

This is the content of launch.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

aws s3 cp s3://folder/myapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myapp.war

catalina.sh run
```

This is my k8s deployment:

```
- command: [bash, -c, bash /scripts/launch.sh]
         image: my_dockerfile
         securityContext:
           allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
           readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
           capabilities:
             drop:
               - ALL
         imagePullPolicy: Always
         name: pod_name
         ports:
           - {containerPort: 8888}
         volumeMounts:
           - {mountPath: /home/nonroot, name: nonroot}
           - {mountPath: /secrets, name: secrets}
```

I've also tried in the Dockerfile

`RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/tomcat/` and `RUN chmod -R a+rwx /usr/local/tomcat/`

But nothing have worked to give me write access to de directory to transfer the file, `ls -l` command shows:
`drwxrwxrwx 1 root root   6 Oct 13 18:07 webapps`

Any hint or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `readOnlyRootFilesystem: true` option means you can't write to any non-volume directory, regardless of Unix permissions.  I might arrange for the war file to be in the image itself, rather than downloading it repeatedly on every single startup.

Comment: I can't arrange the war file in the image itself because the name can change over time, is there a possibility to create another volume to be able to write there?

Comment: When you `COPY` the file into the image, you can give it a fixed name in the image even if it has something like a version name on the host.